# PHP login form sometimes escapes special characters from password

Tags: php, forms, authentication, escaping

So my problem is a little strange and don't really know how it can be explained clearly.

I'm currently testing my website and I have a login form on each top of page, all of it is handled by a template so the code is the same for every login form. I have different levels of files and my root directory looks something like this :

```
/index.php
/photos.php
/videos.php
/users/login.php
/users/register.php
/users/forgot-password.php
```

The password I'm currently using contains a `"` in it. It all works well on the root of the server (index.php, video.php, photo.php) but for some reason once I'm in the files (/users/login.php, /users/register.php)  I cannot log into my account. I figured out that if I escape my password like this `\"` it work.

I even copied the file index.php into the users folder and there is also the same problem.

Here is my function to generate the hash of the password :

```
function generateHash($plainText, $salt = null)
{
    global $db;

    $plainText = trim($db->sql_escape($plainText));


    if ($salt === null)
    {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 25);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = trim($salt);
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 25);
    }

    return $salt . sha1($salt . $plainText);
}
```

Now I'm really lost, I don't know what to try to make this work, so I'm hopping you could help me and find an answer.

Comment: Why are you using PHP to generate the hash? And what do you do with it?

Comment: OK, lets summarize what you say: index.php on top level works with your password. index.php in a directory does not work with your password, but with the backslashed version? I cannot see why your hash generator is to blame then, I suppose something else is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably experience effects from a once active magic_quotes_gpc setting, that has been improperly disabled, e.g. magic quotes were active, but additionally the INSERT with the password was also mysql-escaped. If magic quotes was disabled later, the additional backslash will not be added to the password.

It is not easy to say how to repair this. Probably a good way might be to actually try the plain password first, but if this fails, add another try with "addslashes($password)".

As you are only storing hashed passwords, there is no way to repair the original passwords.

Comment: Well as I said I'm only testing my website so it isn't yet public so I don't have to repair any passwords. And I'm using Bluehost as my hosting server so I don't think that they would have magic quotes enabled. And the password I am testing was made a few minutes before I tested the login form

Comment: @JorisBlanc - You should not be able to "repair" passwords. A password should be between you and the machine. People should not be able to crack them.

Comment: See my comment to your question. Would be great if you could update it with less info about everything else and concentrate on the index.php case.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to SQL escape anything unless it is being directly inserted into a query. As such, that `sql_escape` call is the source of your problems.

As a note, hashing with MD5 is virtually equivalent to using plain-text passwords as the cracking time for something salted is so low as to be hard to measure.

Comment: Well I used the SQL escape to test if that was the source of my problem, without the sql escape I can't log in from any pages of my website. Do you have any good tutorials on how to securely store the passwords ?

Comment: The escaping of the password is way too early, anyways. First you escape it. THEN you hash and salt it. And the result doesn't even come near a database inside this function - so there is no need to sql-escape it inside this function. To prevent sql injection, the escaping has to be done on the string that goes into the sql, which is the result of the hash function, not the password itself.